# Reading Values of XLSB file Python

Tags: python, excel

So my xlsb file contains real-time data fetching and calculations from third party service like Bloomberg. After calculation is done in excel, how to import the file in Python?

I tried methods online, but none worked and returned NA for cells that required real time calculations.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try the latest xlsb2xlsx package on PyPI:

```
pip install xlsb2xlsx
python -m xlsb2xlsx /filepath_with_xlsb_file
```

Then you can use `pandas` with something like:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('your_filepath.xlsx')
```

And work with the `df` object from there.

See https://pypi.org/project/xlsb2xlsx/ for more info.